# Why are my getters and actions not being found using Nuxt and Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm just getting spun up using Nuxt + Vuex. I have a very simple `component` & `store` but the `action` and `getter` aren't being identified by vuex and I'm not sure why.

## versions

```
# nuxt: 2.11
# vuex: 3.1.2
# vue: 2.6.11
```

### store/properties.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const state = () => ({
  properties: []
})

export const getters = {
  allProperties: state => state.properties
}

export const actions = {
  async fetchProperties ({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/properties')
    commit('setProperties', response.data)
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  setProperties: (state, properties) => (state.properties = properties)
}
```

### pages/properties.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ allProperties }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    computed: mapGetters(['allProperties']),
    created () {
      this.fetchProperties()
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['fetchProperties'])
    }
  }
</script>
```

Running this results in

```
[vuex] unknown action type: fetchProperties
[vuex] unknown getter: allProperties
```

[image]

Why isn't the `getter` and the `action` being registered or identified?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's `properties/fetchProperties` and `properties/allProperties`. Files in `store` that are not `mutations/actions/getters` are automagically considered `namespaced` for  Nuxt.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks man, that did it. I completely missed where it had namespace: true in their docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ohgodwhy pointed out, Nuxt namespaces the `store`.

### pages/properties.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ allProperties }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: mapGetters('properties', ['allProperties']),
  created () {
    this.fetchProperties()
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('properties', ['fetchProperties'])
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a novice programmer practicing the VUE. Thank you for the solution, it helped me get through this obstacle.